# Maximizing length of subsequence

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Given a sequence $(a)$ of lenght $n$, such $a_1 = a_n = 1$ and $a_i \in \left \{ -1, 1 \right\}$.

We want to find a subsequence $(b) \subset (a)$ which statisfies the following conditions:

- The length of $(b)$, (let's call it $k$) is the largest possible
- $b_k = b_1 = 1$
- Each prefix sum $b_1$, $b_1+b_2$,  $b_1+b_2 + b_3,\ \ldots\ , b_1 + b_2 + \ldots + b_k$ is $\geq 0$.
- Each suffix sum $b_k$, $b_{k} + b_{k-1}, b_{k} + b_{k-1} + b_{k-2}, \ \ldots\ , b_k + b_{k-1} + \ldots + b_1$ is $\geq 0$.
- Sum of $(b)$ is the biggest possible.

Is it possible to construct linear algorithm to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let $c_0 = 0$ and $c_i = \sum_{j=1}^i a_i$, (which can be done in linear time).  Now the problem becomes -- find $0\le i < k\le n$ such that for all $i\le j<k$ we have $c_i\le c_j \le c_k$ that maximizes $k-i$.  This can be found in a single sweep. (I'll let you work out the details.)

For the problem actually asked:  We want the longest subsequence that begins and ends with 1 and each of the prefix and suffix sums is nonnegative.  First note that all $a_i=1$ are included as including it will only increase the prefix and suffix sums.  In particular $b_1=a_1$ and $b_k=a_n$.  We can construct $(b)$ in two passes.  First pass from $i=1$ to $n$ selecting every $a_i$ such that either $a_i = 1$ or $a_i=-1$ and the prefix condition is not violated in our subsequence (we are greedily selecting everything subject to the prefix condition).  Now pass backwards through the subsequence discarding elements that violate the suffix condition.

Note that since all of the $a_i=1$ are in $(b)$ the sum of $(b)$ is just the count of $a_i=b_j=1$ minus the count of the $b_j=-1$ and so is twice the count of $a_i=1$ minus the length of $(b)$, a function of the length.  So any other subsequence satisfying the conditions having the same length will have the same sum.

Comment: The subsequence $b$ need not be contiguous.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about one case. The sum of $(b)$ must be biggest possible. Albo $b$ need not be contiguous.

Comment: What about if $a_i \in -1,0,1$ ? It makes problem harder?

Comment: According to your version of problem, how to do it in single sweep? Are you assumming that $c_i \geq c_{i-1}$ ?

Comment: I missed that it need not be contiguous, I'll add that after dinner (that is a different problem).

Comment: Can you write also about first problem? (b) need to be contiguous and all prefix and suffix sums need to be >= 0. Also sum of $b$ needn't to be max. We considering only lenght of $b$. For example for sequence 1 1 -1 1 1 is 5, for sequence 1 -1 -1 is 1 and for -1 1 1 -1 1 is 4.

Comment: I've very interested in approaching many cases of this problem :) Nice problem from my algorithm teacher.

Comment: If the subsequence need not be contiguous, and you want the sum of the $b_i$ to be as large as possible then just choose all the $b_i=1$.  The  case where we consider the length of the subsequence is more interesting.  I'll get that later.

Comment: @Deinst You want the sum to be as large as possible under the constraint that the length is as large as possible; so there might not be enough $1$s in the original sequence.

Comment: @Yuval I still don't understand, The longest such $(b)$ sequence will contain all the 1's from $(a)$, adding a 1 does not cause a violation of any of the constraints.  So the sum of the elements of $(b)$ is a function of its length.  What am I missing?

Comment: Here is an example: $1,-1,1$. Your suggestion $1,1$ is of length $2$, while $1,-1,1$ is of length $3$ (though smaller sum).

Comment: Yes, I agree.  What I was saying is that given the constraints, all longest sequences have the same sum.  For example if a = 1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1  the longest acceptable subsequence has length 5 (there are 4 such subsequences, and all have sum 1).  The constraint asking to choose the minimum sum adds nothing to the original problem.